# check youtube video is embeddable <yt:noembed> via xml

Tags: php, xml, youtube, youtube-api, embeddable

I have following link http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/tYMYv1zsAxE and it return an xml file in which is located noembed tag in case the video is not embeddable.

i want to create a loop on list of videos to check which is embeddable and which is not.

Comment: Are you asking for help writing a loop in PHP? This doesn't seem like it's related to xml, youtube, youtube-api, or embeddable at all—just a basic PHP question.

Comment: no, the thing is i can't read the xml file, no matter if i use `simplexml_load_file` or `curl` i can't read the <yt:noembed> tag, they return plain text not the xml format. @JeffPosnick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarification, it sounds like you're asking a question about parsing XML. Here's an alternative: get back JSON, and parse that. You can make a request like

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/tYMYv1zsAxE?v=2&alt=jsonc&prettyprint=true

and then look at the data->accessControl->embed element within the JSON response.

Or, you know, just parse and access the YouTube API XML exactly like you'd parse the XML from any other source. There's nothing magic going on with the YouTube API XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vidID = "tYMYv1zsAxE";
$url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$vidID?v=2&alt=jsonc&prettyprint=true";
$json = file_get_contents($url, true);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
echo $json_output->data->accessControl->embed;
```

Simple way to check if youtube video is embeddable.

Thanks to @Jeff Posnick